# Help optimising delete statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, optimization, delete

Using SQL Server 2012 Standard - I'm running a delete on a table based on the contents of another table. It's taking rather a long time (5 hours) and doesn't seem to be optimal to me, would appreciate some input optimising the statement:

```
delete from [dbo].[tbl1]
where exists (
    select *
    from [dbo].[tbl2] t 
    where [dbo].[tbl1].[col1] = t.[col1]
    and [dbo].[tbl1].[col2] = t.[col2]
    and [dbo].[tbl1].[col3] = t.[col3]  
)
```

The columns are as follows:

```
tbl1.col1 varchar(10)
tbl1.col2 datetime
tbl1.col3 varchar(60)
tbl2.col1 varchar(10)
tbl2.col2 datetime
tbl2.col3 varchar(30)
```

I realise that the datatype on `col3` differs, I know this is bad, but would this mean the index cannot be used?

There is a non-unique clustered index on each table (not covered by this query) and a non-clustered index on both, covering all three columns included in the where clause.

`tbl1` contains ~1.2 billion rows, `tbl2` contains ~30 million rows. I'm expecting around 30 million rows to be deleted from `tbl1`.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: FYI, `tbl1` and `tbl2` are on differing filegroups, but on the same disk (SAN). Also, here is the execution plan:

[image: execution plan]

Comment: Try DELETE t1 from tbl1 t1 inner join tbl2 t2 on tl1.col1= t2.co1 and t1.col2=t2.col2 and t1.col3 = t2.col3

Comment: Try the statement posted by Sporri but before that update statistics.  That should work.

Comment: I actually changed the statement from using a join initially, the updated version was a good bit quicker actually.

Comment: Would you be able to drop the indexes, delete the data, and then rebuild the indexes? On delete operations, the indexes have to be changed too so this is just a thought.  Not sure if that'd be feasible or you'd be able to test to see if that'd work in your environment, but it's just a thought of something you may or may not be able to easily test win minimal impact of your DBs and system.

Comment: I had considered this, but dropping then creating indexes on a 1.2 billion row table...

Comment: If you could test and see what the performance difference is on rebuilding the indexes after dropping and then deleting the data and rebuilding versus your other way I suppose. I'm not sure if one would take more hours than the other but if you have a way to test, it may be a simple thing to try at least once if you feel comfortable with that sort of solution.

Comment: This may be worth reading too depending on your recovery model if you do move forward with testing a solution of this nature for index dropping and then rebuilding once the data is deleted and how this could affect SQL logging. . . http://blog.dbi-services.com/sql-server-online-index-rebuild-and-minimally-logged-operations/

Comment: @ypercube Yes, I think that the `MERGE JOIN` with no preceding `Sort` operator indicates that both tables are indexed by `(col1,col2,col3)`, and the `Stream Aggregate` indicates that this is not a unique index on `tbl2`

Comment: Have you tried using [sp_whoisactive](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx) or [sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190326.aspx) to see the waits and disk I/O performance and stalls? I'd guess that the primary bottleneck is disk I/O on the transaction log. Is the transaction log on a separate physical disk? You might also consider batching the deletes if the `Sort` operator is spilling to tempdb, but it's hard to tell if that's the case based on only the estimated plan.

Comment: Check to see if there are any delete triggers on tbl1. I have seen cases where audit triggers that log old values to an audit table on delete can cause delete performance issues. You could also check the foreign keys on the table to see if cascading deletes are turned on, in addition to the other suggestions around stats and disk io monitoring.

Comment: Yes, index on the three columns and no primary key on either. Clustered index on another column not included in the statement. Both tables are essentially the same. The tlogs are indeed on a separate disk too.

Comment: FYI - no triggers or any other activity on the server, still in build phase at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this kind of performance issue before, and breaking the delete up into discrete steps of a fixed size is what ended up doing the trick.  It allows SQL Server to commit changes more frequently, which is generally easier on the transaction log.

```
SELECT 'Begin Delete'; --gives @@ROWCOUNT a value
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
    delete top (100000) from [dbo].[tbl1]
    where exists (
        select *
        from [dbo].[tbl2] t 
        where [dbo].[tbl1].[col1] = t.[col1]
        and [dbo].[tbl1].[col2] = t.[col2]
        and [dbo].[tbl1].[col3] = t.[col3]  
    );
```

The optimal batch size just depends on your server and what it can handle.  I've found 100,000 to be a safe size for me, and we've not got anything particularly powerful, so you may be able to get away with more.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the delete itself is what is taking the time.
You should test [disable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177456.aspx), delete, and then [rebuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx) the indexes.

I know you said you tried a join but this would be a quick test

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[tbl1] DISABLE;
delete top (1000) tbl1Del 
from [dbo].[tbl1] and tbl1Del 
join [dbo].[tbl2] t 
  on tbl1Del.[col1] = t.[col1]
 and tbl1Del.[col2] = t.[col2]
 and tbl1Del.[col3] = t.[col3]; 
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[tbl1] REBUILD;
```

Run this select and you will know if determining which rows to delete is the problem.

```
select count(*) 
  from [dbo].[tbl1] and tbl1Del 
  join [dbo].[tbl2] t 
    on tbl1Del.[col1] = t.[col1]
   and tbl1Del.[col2] = t.[col2]
   and tbl1Del.[col3] = t.[col3]
```

Comment: Thanks for this but that rebuild will take hours on the 1.2 billion row table, far from a quick test sadly. I'm not sure I'm going to be able to squeeze any more out of this and will just have to live with it, or get some SSDs :-)

Comment: It has been running for 5 hours.  Are you sure a rebuild would not be faster?  Not squeezing very hard if you you are not willing to give it a try.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but the initial index creation took around 10 hours. I believe this delete will only take place once a month - it might be a good opportunity to rebuild the index anyway as it'll certainly be a bit fragmented afterwards.

Comment: Copy 1 million rows to another table and test both ways.   I have some inserts on 100 million row tables and disable and rebuild is way faster.